# What's a simple way to undelete a file in subversion?

Tags: svn, version-control

These instructions are a little intimidating and confusing: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch04s04.html#svn-ch-4-sect-4.3 .
And also they don't seem to mention that it's much simpler if you haven't yet checked in after doing the "`svn rm`" [1].

So I thought this would be a good place to record a simpler answer for those googling for this.

[1] To an svn newbie, it might appear that "`svn rm`" immediately destroys the file.  I recall doing `svn rm` thinking that would just remove it from source control and freaking out when the file itself actually disappeared.  So a sub-question is, what's the right way to remove a file from version control without actually removing your local copy?

Comment: `svn status | grep "^D" | awk '{print $2}' | xargs svn revert`

Answer (score 94, accepted):

If you just did

```
svn rm foo.txt
```

then you can undo that with simply

```
svn revert foo.txt
```

If you already checked in after doing the "`svn rm`" then you can look at the log (`svn log`), find the last revision where the file existed, and grab it from that version.

One way to do that is to merge in the old revision that has the file.  Assuming the current revision is 123 and the last version with that file is 120, then do this:

```
svn merge -r123:120
```

Maybe first do a dry run to make sure it won't do anything you don't want:

```
svn --dry-run merge -r123:120
```

---

For the sub-question, how to remove a file from svn without removing the local copy:

```
svn rm foo.txt --keep-local
```

Or, of course, you could just copy to a temp file before svn rm'ing and then copy back:

```
cp foo.txt foo.txt-tmp
svn rm foo.txt
(svn ci -m "just removed foo.txt from the repository")
cp foo.txt-tmp foo.txt
```

Comment: The problem with merge is that it looses the previous history of the file. svn cp as detailed in Stefan's answer is probably better, as well as easier to understand.

Comment: I found if change the version order, it is only add the removed file to current working copy, without others change of none removed file, e.g. `svn merge -r120:123 svn_url .`

Comment: `svn revert` did not work recursively and I had to do `svn stat | egrep ^D | cut -c8- | xargs svn revert`

Comment: My problem with the "reverse merge" is that it creates a Tree Conflict.

Answer (score 44):

for whatever reason, the `-r` arg wasn't working for me (svn version 1.6.9). I tried before and after the `src`, but kept getting a message that the file was not found in the current revision (duh). Same with --revision. Using the @ style syntax worked though:

```
svn cp url/to/removed/foo.txt@4 foo.txt
```

Comment: Never know what's the most simple way to determine last working version but this statement is gold.

Comment: what is the @ style syntax?

Comment: Typically you'd `-r` for specifying a revision number (see [Revision Specifiers](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.tour.revs.specifiers.html)). The `@` notation is for peg revision (see [Peg and Operative Revisions](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.pegrevs.html))

Comment: If you don't want to worry yourself with finding the *actual URL* to your repo, you can use `^/path/from/repo/root` instead. For example, in my case, I used `^/trunk/path/to/my/file.js` to restore a file that was originally located at `path/to/my/file.js` in my working copy (which is `^/trunk`).

Comment: This answer provides a lot of clarity to a concept I've been very confused about.  I, too, was unable to "undelete" a file with -r <previous revision> with an error message claiming it's not in the current revision.  After reading the link above about peg revisions, I take that to mean subversion wants me to specify a peg revision wth the at sign where that file DID exist, so it knows *which* (potential) copy of oldfile.c I'm asking for.

Answer (score 33):

To remove a file but keep it in the working copy, use

```
svn rm foo.txt --keep-local
```

To get a file back after you've committed the remove, you can use either the merge command, or the copy command - both will preserve the file history. Since the merge way is already described elsewhere, here's the copy way:

```
svn rm foo.txt
svn ci foo.txt -m "removed file"
(now at r5 as an example)
svn cp url/to/removed/foo.txt -r4 foo.txt
svn ci foo.txt -m "got file back"
```

Comment: For me to work, the copy command must be a bit different : svn cp url/to/removed/foo.txt@4 -r4 foo.txt      ---- without the @4 I get a "path not found" error

Comment: Yes, for me I found "url/to/removed" by running `svn info` in the directory and looking at the "URL" field. Then I also had to do the "@4" trick, and the "-r4" wasn't necessary. Interestingly, the file log history is restored, with the exception of the delete entry!

Answer (score 10):

For TortoiseSVN users, this is very easily accomplished via the Repo Browser. Within the Repo Browser switch to the revision before the file was deleted (you can change the version using the "Revision:" button at the top right):

[image]

You should then be able to see the deleted file in its original location in the Repo Browser. Right-click on it and choose "Copy to working copy...":

[image]

The file will then be restored to your working copy ready to commit (as though svn added) and with its log history intact.

Comment: It did not work for me with 1.14.2 version of TortoiseSVN. Only copied revision log called, no other old logs..

Answer (score 4):

To revert a deleted  file in SVN. Find the revision number just before delete (say 341). Then revert that file alone to that revision number.

```
svn up -r341 [path_to_deletedFile]
```

Comment: This gets another local copy, but the file remains "deleted" in the repository. Your next "svn up" will see it disappear.

Answer (score 1):

i used the copy menu item from the previous revision using tortoise, worked for me and kept the history.

Comment: Sounds promising, can you give more details ?  From where exactly do you issue the copy command ?