# Can I merge files in git?

Tags: git, github

I have three files `Shell-ijk-ArrayList.java`, `Shell-ijk-Vektor.java` and `Shell-ikj-ArrayList.java` in this [git-repository](https://github.com/MartinThoma/matrix-multiplication/tree/master/Java). I have "merged" them manually to `MatrixMultiplication.java`. Now I would like to get rid of the other three, but I want to keep the history of them. What is the best way to do this?

I have found [git merge-file](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge-file.html), but when I try

```
git merge-file MatrixMultiplication.java Shell-ijk-ArrayList.java Shell-ijk-Vektor.java
```

I get

```
error: Could not stat MatrixMultiplication.java
```

I could simply remove the old files with `git rm`, but then I'll lose the history, won't I?

I could also move it with `git mv`, but what would be a good folder for outdated files?

Comment: Merge them in what way exactly? These files look very different from one to another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like you are merging different files with separate logic into one file? That is not what git merge-file is for.

From *git help merge-file*:

```
git merge-file incorporates all changes that lead from the <base-file> to 
<other-file>  into <current-file>. The result ordinarily goes into 
<current-file>. 

git merge-file is useful for combining separate changes to an original. 
Suppose <base-file> is the original, and both <current-file> and <other-file> 
are modifications of <base-file>, then git merge-file combines both changes.
```

Example (also from the help page):

```
 git merge-file README.my README README.upstream
       combines the changes of README.my and README.upstream since README, 
       tries to merge them and writes the result into README.my.
```

To combine logic from completely separate files into one, you are right in combining them manually.

Deleting a file does not remove its history, you can see the log of a deleted file with:

```
git log -- <path_to_file>
```

See related Q/A:

[Git: How to search for a deleted file in the project commit history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203515/git-how-to-search-for-a-deleted-file-on-the-project-history)

[Find and restore a deleted file in a Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953481/restore-a-deleted-file-in-a-git-repo)

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you know if the history was lost in `subversion`? (btw., nice Blog)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/497670/whats-a-simple-way-to-undelete-a-file-in-subversion

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure git merge-file is what you need. This sounds more like code refactoring/shuffling around.

git rm keeps history, and is non-retroactive. If you revert to a previous version they will be there. When I go and check my old check ins the files I "git rm"'d are still there with full history.

Answer (score 1):

`git rm` won't loose the history of those files: see "[Querying deleted content in git](http://feeding.cloud.geek.nz/2010/07/querying-deleted-content-in-git.html)":

> To see the commit history of that file, you can't do it the usual way:

```
$ git log file2
fatal: ambiguous argument 'file2': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions
```

> Instead, you need to do this:

```
$ git log -- file2
```

As for the `git-merge-file`, try to apply it on an empty, but added to the index, `MatrixMultiplication.java` file.