# I want to redownload complete application folder from svn, as current synced folder corrupted

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, ankhsvn

I am using MVC3, ASP.NET with Visual Studio 2012.

I am using Subversion with TortoiseSVN in the desktop and AnkhSVN in visual Studio.

It appears that I have made a silly/novice error in deleting the contents of the local folder in the desktop. I did use TortoiseSVN to do this.

All my files on store in an online repo.

I had hoped to just "Update" back to the previous version, but SVN reports that this files are "deleted".

What is the best way to just redownload a specific release's complete fileset? I would be happy to use TortoiseSVN or ANkhSVN. I just need to get the application folders back and complete to specific version, and synced with SVN.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/497670/whats-a-simple-way-to-undelete-a-file-in-subversion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you made any changes in Working Copy and didn't yet commit these changes (any changes, deleting is also change) you can "Revert" this changes and undo to state of vanilla revision

RClick on folder with deleted content - `TortoiseSVN` - `Revert`, select all detected deletes and get it back

Answer (score 1):

Right click on folder, TortoiseSVN->Revert will get your files back